# Cannot convert IQueryable<T> AsEnumerable because T has a Guid property

Tags: entity-framework, linq, guid

I have the following EF class:

```
class Product
{
   public Guid ProductGuid { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

derived from a DB class where `ProductGuid` is a **uniqueidentifier** and `ProductName` is a **nvarchar**.

Consider `productContext` as the context:

```
var products = productContext.Products;
productList = products.ToList(); 

OR

productList = products.AsEnumerable();
```

The first instruction is executed correctly the second (both) launches an exception at runtime (it compiles correctly):

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to
>   Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

I tried everything it does not work. I have other tables with Guid field but it never launches such exception. What can be the cause?

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to use the GUID type in that property? Wouldn't string do it for you anyway?

try replacing GUID. use String instead.

Comment: I cannot, first of all I use .NET 3.5 hence I cannot use neither ToString() nor the sql functions (available in .net 4.0) in LINQ to Entities. I can use ToString() if I convert the IQueryable to IEnumerable but this is the very problem